# PDF text extraction error in r_Invalid Font Weight

Tags: pdf, text, fonts, extract

I'm working on text extraction from PDF files in r. 
For some reason, I get a below error.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
theme <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
theme
length(theme)
lapply(theme, length)

corp <- Corpus(URISource(files), readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))

head(corp)
```

my error message is here

[image]

PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
PDF error: Invalid Font Weight
PDF error: Invalid Font Weight